# How to compare my string to the return in python

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I have this code

```
log_in = f'SELECT user_name,fname FROM users;'
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(log_in)
result = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
print(type(result))
print(result)
print('bfuqua' in result)
if 'bfuqua' in result:
    unique = False
    print('That user name already exists. Please try again.')
```

When I print the type I get `<class 'list'>` as the return type, `[('bfuqua',)]` as the data from the result variable. My problem is that it should be entering into the if statement but the return from the third print statement says `False`. It comes back as `True` when I put `result[0]`, but I need to be able to scan the whole list for the string. I don't know what is going on.

If there are any other ways I can check to see if the string is in the return from the query, I am more than open to hear it!

Comment: Why don't you query the user you're looking for directly and then check if there is a result?

Comment: Because this is a create_user function and it needs to check and see if the username already exists

Comment: The way this is currently formatted this is not a function. Why would you not be able to query the user directly in a function though? Try this `log_in = "SELECT user_name, fname FROM users WHERE user_name = 'bfuqua';"`. If there is a result, it means the user exists, if there isn't, it does not.

Comment: Yes, I agree @iuvbio, but make sure it is SQL injection safe.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you would like to use your code you can iterate over result to achieve what you want:

```py
for i in result:
    if 'bfuqua' in i:
        unique = False
        print('That user name already exists. Please try again.')
```

But if you want to do it in a way suggested by @iuvbio I'd do it like:

```py
def check_if_user_exists(username):
    #by using "with" you dont need to worry about closing the connection
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        log_in = "SELECT user_name, fname FROM users WHERE user_name = %s"
        cursor.execute(log_in, (username,))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    # If there is no user, the result will be a tuple with 0 length
    if len(result) == 0:
        print("No user named {}".format(username))
        # So here you can create user
    else:
        print("User {} already exists".format(username))
        # Here you can create a notification for a client that the username already exists
check_if_user_exists("bfuqua")
```

I'm also a beginner so dont treat it like the one and only good solution but it works for me. Hope I was able to help :)

Comment: Please don't create SQL strings using string formatting!  Doing this means a correctly crafted username could modify the SQL and modify data, steal information, or crash the server.  It's really really dangerous.  There are tools in the SQL packages to create "parametised" queries, and you pass the variables as parameters that the SQL library will look after correctly.